# Switching from letsencrypt (client) to acme-client - where is my account key?

Tags: letsencrypt

I started using letsencrypt when there was an "official" client called `letsencrypt`. I now want to change to [`acme-client`](https://kristaps.bsd.lv/acme-client/) - that is, the C implementation.

I think I manage to configure my sites, and find the certificates for them, but I get the error

```
acme-client: https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-authz: bad HTTP: 403
acme-client: transfer buffer: [{ "type": "urn:acme:error:unauthorized",
"detail": "No registration exists matching provided key", "status": 403 }] 
(120 bytes)
```

I don't think I got the account key right. Where did `letsencrypt` store that? I find a directory called `/etc/letsencrypt/accounts`, but below, there are no `pem`-files, only `json`with strange content...

So my questions are:

- Did `letsencrypt` store the account key in `pem`-format?

  - If so, where can I find it?
  - If not - is the key stored anywhere in a way that is transformable to `pem`-format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, much easier, is to re-register the account using

```
acme-client -DAvv <domain>
```

after having opened port 80 and configured `httpd` to answer calls with the additional

```
location "/.well-known/acme-challenge/*" { 
    root "/acme" 
    root strip 2 
}
```